# Cannot autowire RequestMappingHandleMapping in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm trying to enable Swagger on a REST API created using the Spring MVC framework. I'm attempting to use [swagger-springmvc](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc) to automatically generate the json for it, and am having a problem. The root cause appears to be that the swagger-springmvc project expects to find a RequestMappingHandlerMapping instance registered with Spring, but that bean does not exist. When starting up the server, I encounter this error:

```
No matching bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]
```

I found [a relevant thread](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/issues/160) on the project's forums. The only suggestion there that seems relevant to me is to add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to my spring configuration, which I don't currently have.

However, when I add that line, I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:default-servlet-handler'.
```

I know that this is usually due to an issue with the schema location definitions, but that doesn't appear to be the case here. I use several other tags within the `mvc` prefix, so it doesn't seem right to me that this one should fail. Here is the header of my xml configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="us.co.state.judicial.icces.webservices.rest" />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean name="serverUtil" class="us.co.state.judicial.icces.webservices.util.WebServerUtil" />

    <bean name="swaggerConfig" class="us.co.state.judicial.icces.webservices.config.SwaggerConfig" />

    ...(some extra beans to define internally accessible services chopped off)
</beans>
```

So I guess, ultimately, my question is in two parts:
1) Does anyone know why `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` isn't working for me, or does anyone know of another reason why Swagger wouldn't be able to autowire any instances of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` into my project? I'm happy to post further details about my configuration if that would help.

Comment: Please show some context around your `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out for me @Dirk, I've updated my original question so that there is more than just the header of the config file listed.

Comment: You appear to be using an older version of Spring framework - can you please confirm that you are using Spring 3.2+

Comment: @BijuKunjummen This shouldn't be the problem as the required xsd is also included in rev 3.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.0.x/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd#L101

Comment: @BijuKunjummen was completely correct. I should have read the full documentation of the plugin before posting here, my mistake. I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You appear to be using an older version of Spring framework - can you please confirm that you are using Spring 3.2+ –  Biju Kunjummen yesterday

This comment contained the answer. Silly mistake on my part, many thanks to Biju for the help.